# Converting ASP connection to PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a pre-existing ASP script that I've been tasked with converting to PHP. The connection string is like so:

```
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");

if(strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"],"localhost")){
$conn->Open("dsn=xxxxx;uid=xxxxx;pwd=xxxxxxxx");
}elseif(strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"],"dpsql")){
$conn->Open("dsn=xxxxx;uid=xxxxx;pwd=xxxxxxxx");
}else{
$conn->Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com; Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx; User ID=xxxxxxxxxx; Password=xxxxxxx;network=xxxxxxx");
}
```

Most of the examples I can find involve use of the PHP COM Extension however I am on a Linux hosted PHP version and was told by my Hosting Provided that the COM Extension was for windows. I've spent a couple hours trying to figure out how to create a connection object that works with all of these but I'm more front-end oriented. I tried using a PDO connection but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***UPDATE***

I've been able to connect using PDO with the sqlite driver as that's all HostGator has installed for me. Not very familiar with PDO but I'll Google around and see what I can figure out on how to use it. Currently stuck on:

```
$conn = $c->prepare($g_sql);
$conn->Execute();
```

returning erro:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function Execute() on a non-object
```

Comment: I've never seen ASP like that before - is that PerlScript you're using as your scripting language

Comment: Oh sorry, this is actually the ASP re-written as PHP using the COM object to create an ADO connection. However, I'm on a Linux server with HostGator and it doesn't support the COM object.

Comment: Added some error ouputting and it's saying that the table I'm connecting to doesn't exist. Guessing this relates to the server being remote as John said below and I need to gain access first.

Comment: Found out PDO will attempt to create the database once connected if it doesn't exist. I'm guessing this is why it's connecting but not finding the table, in the original connection string it's declaring a network location, not sure how to do this with my PDO command.

Comment: SQLite isn't SQL Server, it's a different database. Hostgator need to install a SQL Server driver for you, and if they won't you need to find another host.  Hooking up a UNIX hosted site to SQL Server is quite an unusual thing to do, and Hostgator looks the sort of company which provides "off the shelf" solutions

Comment: I see, thanks so much for your help. I agree it is quite unusual but, it's the hand I was dealt. My hesitation was due to the complex nature of the company I work for but I guess I'll have to submit a request to contact HostGator and hope my IT guy communicates it properly :( So backwards that i'm not the one with direct access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$server = 'xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com';
$conn = mssql_connect($server, 'youruserid', 'yourpassword');
```

Also, check this, (unless your on UNIX, in which case there's probably an equivalent procedure you have to go through

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php

Comment: I had tried a simple mssql_connect script but it says it's unable to connect. Currently the third connection is the one I'm testing and I'm wondering if the network declaration has something to do with why it's not working? I'm not really familiar with providing a network location for a connection string.

Comment: If it isn't a local connection then your sql server is very likely to be behind a firewall.

Your question is basically how to connect to a remote sql server with php on a unix server, so I'd tag your question "php" and "sql-server" and forget the rest. You're certainly not using Classic ASP or OLEDB - which is a COM object and irrelevant on UNIX.  I think a sql server expert is most likely to have the answers

Comment: Is your database Sql Server Express - in which case you need to add "|SQLEXPRESS" after the server address?

Answer (score 1):

PHP has several options that you can use to connect to a MS SQL Databse.

The best option for what you need is the `COM("ADODB.Connection")` class.

Try doing.

```
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");

$conn->open("Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com; Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx; User ID=xxxxxxxxxx; Password=xxxxxxx;network=xxxxxxx");

$query = $conn->execute("SELECT field FROM table");
```

You can read more about it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php

Comment: If you read my question a bit more you'll see I don't have access to the COM class.